# How come Go Ether and Ethereum Wallet both say 0 ether but Etherchain says .05?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp

When I try `web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("<My Account>"), "ether")` I get 0. Also when I install and run the Ethereum Wallet, I see my account but it says 0. But when I open etherchain and input my address I see

`Balance:    0.05455706564854493 Ether ($27.74) | Buy more`

I tried

`eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[1], to:'<other address>', value: web3.toWei(0.05, "ether"), gas:21000});`

and I get `Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value`

Where as the Mist application just sits and spins syncing and downloading blocks. If I choose "Launch App" then I see my wallet but the balance is 0,

What am I doing wrong?

**READ BEFORE YOU SHRUG THIS OFF IF YOU SEARCHED!**

Actually I wasn't doing anything wrong it just doesn't work like that.

I needed to import my UTC into Metamask and it worked perfect, I waited around for 4 days and tried to sync thanks to you guys saying it was a duplicate.

:-(

Comment: You need to wait for Mist to finish syncing. Then you'll see your balance update to the right value.

Comment: That is taking FOREVER, and what is the excuse for Web3?

Comment: Did you connect web3 to a running Ethereum node?

Comment: To be sure it is not a duplicate, how did you sync?

Comment: I did connect to a geth instance using geth --rpc console then putting the send through. I am synching though mist, so far two days and 10% :-(

Comment: @Jackie To sync it requires a computer with above 8gb of ram and a SDD disk. Geth currently will take forever with a HDD. Search for "light" synchornization mode, it doesn't download the blockchain, but make queries synchronized nodes instead.

Comment: I have an SSD and intel Rapid storage as well as 8gbs of 3000 DDR 4(5?) RAM. I am running a 1050TI and a 1070.